# Find a process, script or connection that consume highest resource in Apache2 / Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am having issues with my WordPress site hosted on EC2. Today I've noticed when looking at the EC2 monitoring charts that the CPU is constant between 30-35% usage and I have a very high "network in" and "network out" usage of around 2,000,000 to 4,000,000 bytes a minute on average. This wasn't like that before, much less around 70,000/minute.

I have access to the server via SSH.

I inspect the open connection and saw 9 IPs with around 1-7 connection, accept for the server IP with 46 connections. I assume that this is a kind of attack that comes from a script or external attack.

My question is, what command do I need to enter in Apache2 (under Ubuntu OS) to know which process or script consumes the highest amount of network activity and CPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a perfect solution, but if it's urgent, I'll give it a shot.

First, you cannot really say which process uses certain ressources, when you're using Apache with the PHP. You're either using Prefork with mod_php or one of the other MPMs with a FCGI/FPM. In any case, the PHP processes are very short living, and there are hundreds or thousands of them.

If you don't have some service-specific monitoring, you have some quick'n'dirty options to approach this problem:

1) Find out from which IP addresses the most requests come:

```
cut -f1 -d ' ' /var/log/apache2/*.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -n 50
```

This will give you a list of the most requests by IP adresses. Now pick the ones with the highest amount and take a sample from the log files:

```
grep xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /var/log/apache2/*.log | tail -n 30
```

Now you should see what files they request.

By the way, usually the last column in the log files should be the time in µs it took to process the request. Maybe there's something to find, too. For example, if your server is infested by a bot which infects other sites or machines, there may be some very long-running scripts, because they need to connect to external machines.

2) You could temporarily insert some sort of “stopwatch” into the main file of WordPress, the `/index.php` file. This would be some simple code at the beginning and the end of this file, for example:

```
<?php
// ...
$t0 = microtime(true);
$m0 = memory_get_peak_usage(true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

$data = array(
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    sprintf('%0.7f', microtime(true) - $t0),
    sprintf('%0.7f', memory_get_peak_usage(true) - $m0),
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
);

@file_put_contents(__DIR__."/clients.log", implode(' ', $data)."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

This way, you can find out more about time and memory consumption of the request, and the exact URL. Of course, you can collect much more, custom information this way.

Keep in mind that this means a write access to this file on each request, so there will be a huge performance penality.

By the way, if those requests really hurt you, and they come from one or a few IP addresses, simply block each address with `iptables`:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

Hope this helps.